# How to save field data

Tags: 7, entities

I need to programmatically save field data (during node save I want to take the title & path alias and store it in a link field called `field_alternative_titles_title`).

Which functions can I use here? Do I use `field_attach_insert` or `hook_field_storage_pre_insert` to save the link field?

Comment: The nature of the code will obviously depend on the specifics - can you edit your question and show the code you've tried, explaining where it's going wrong?

Comment: I hope that made it clearer

Comment: I think so...if I understand you right, `hook_node_presave()` might be the best place. It gives you access to the whole node before changes get sent to the database, and you can safely manipulate field data before it gets persisted

Comment: what entity your field is attached to? is it attached to the same bundle? or you want to store it directly to DB?

Comment: My field is attached to a field collection item, and that field collection item is attached to a content type of mine

Comment: What I want to be able to do Is to just populate the field, and then associate it via bundle with the field collection item it is attached to (field_alternative_titles).
But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: so during saving a node of content type A you want to store a value in a field which is not attached to that content type?

Comment: One more thing , I wont realize if you have answered my question if you don't mention me using @

Comment: @Alireza Tabatabaeian The field isn't technically attached to the content type, but the field collection that it is attached to is attached to the content type

Answer (score 2):

At first you need to implement `hook_node_presave($node)`

> Act on a node being inserted or updated.
>
> This hook is invoked from node_save() before the node is saved to the
>   database. Parameters
>
> $node: The node that is being inserted or updated.

So it reacts when a node is going to be saved , then you have to check if the node type is the proper node type . then setting field value , so this is some code snippet :

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  if($node->type == "Your Node Type") {
      //dsm($node);//it will show the structure of node
      // as example
      $data = $node->title.'-'.drupal_get_path_alias('node/'$node->nid);
      $node->field_alternative_titles_title[$node->language][0]['value'] = "data";//check the node structure,this code wont work for sure
  }
}
```

of-course this is just an snippet , to make it work you have to know the structure of your content type , [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module will help you , install and enable it so dsm function will work.

Comment: Will my field_alternative_titles_title table in my database get populated with this code? @Alireza Tabatabaeian

Comment: It had to, if the node which is going to be saved contains field_alternative_titles_title , then it will affected in DB

Comment: Now, if the node doesn't contain the field_alternative_titles_title field, but instead contains the field collection item field_alternative_titles, and the field collection item field_alternative_titles contains the field field_alternative_titles_title. Would it still work if that was the case?

Comment: if it is a part of node (no matter how or how deep just seen in form in enough in this case) yes it will works but you have to address it right . maybe $node->field_alternative_titles_title is not the right destination , to find the right destination use dsm function